# Unit test with LiveData Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-looper, android-livedata

I cannot make liveData.postValue working in while trying to make unit test. I have been checking in google for a solution and this is the code I have now.

```
public class ProjectListViewModelTest {

    GetProjectList getProjectList = Mockito.mock(GetProjectList.class);
    ProjectModel.Project project = new ProjectModel.Project("testing",
            "this is a test",
            "https://logo.jpg",
            new ProjectModel.Company("cat"),
            "20150404",
            "active");
    List<ProjectModel.Project> projects = Arrays.asList(project);
    ProjectModel.ProjectList projectsList = new ProjectModel.ProjectList(projects);

    ProjectsListViewModel projectsListViewModel;

    private PublishSubject<ProjectModel.ProjectList> projectsListPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    @Rule public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpRxSchedulers() {
        Scheduler immediate = new Scheduler() {
            @Override
            public Disposable scheduleDirect(@NonNull Runnable run, long delay, @NonNull TimeUnit unit) {
                return super.scheduleDirect(run, 0, unit);
            }

            @Override
            public Scheduler.Worker createWorker() {
                return new ExecutorScheduler.ExecutorWorker(Runnable::run);
            }
        };

        RxJavaPlugins.setInitIoSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> immediate);
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitComputationSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> immediate);
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitNewThreadSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> immediate);
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitSingleSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> immediate);
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> immediate);
    }

    @Before
    @Throws(exceptionClasses = Exception.class)
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        projectsListViewModel = new ProjectsListViewModel(getProjectList);
        when(getProjectList.execute()).thenReturn(projectsListPublishSubject.take(1).singleOrError());
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecuteGetProjectsListSuccess() {
        LiveData<List<ProjectModel.MapProject>> liveData = projectsListViewModel.getLiveData();
        ProjectModel.MapProject expectedResult = new ProjectModel.MapProject(
                "testing", "this is a test", "https://logo.jpg",
                "cat", "2015-04-04", "active");
        projectsListViewModel.getProjects();
        projectsListPublishSubject.onNext(projectsList);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, liveData.getValue().get(0));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDownClass(){
        RxAndroidPlugins.reset();
    }
```

The code that I have in `setUpRxSchedulers` is mandatory in order to avoid the same error (`Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked`) with Rx. But I cannot solve this error that I get when calling liveData.post(projectList). In all the forums that I checked they say that with `@Rule public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();` the problem should be solved. But is not my case.

I put here the viewmodel as well in case it can help:

```
public class ProjectsListViewModel extends ViewModel {

    GetProjectList getProjectList;
    MutableLiveData<List<ProjectModel.MapProject>> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public ProjectsListViewModel(GetProjectList getProjectList){
        this.getProjectList = getProjectList;
    }

    public LiveData<List<ProjectModel.MapProject>> getLiveData(){
        return liveData;
    }

    public void getProjects(){
        getProjectList.execute()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map(ProjectModel.ProjectList::getProjects)
                .toObservable().flatMapIterable(projects -> projects)
                .map(project -> project.convertToMapProject()).toList()
        .subscribe(projectsList ->
            liveData.setValue(projectsList));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The usage of `InstantTaskExecutorRule` will actually solve this.

I think the issue is that in JUnit 5 the `@Rule` annotation doesn't seem to be supported anymore ([as Extensions are now the way to go](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-migration#6-new-test-rules-annotations)). The code will compile successfully, but the rule just won't be applied.

#### There are (at least) two solutions to this:

#### Use JUnit 4

Is definitely the quicker, may not be the best depending on how much you need JUnit 5.

This can be done just by changing the annotation of your `setup` method from `@BeforeEach` to `@Before` and by importing the `@Test` annotation from JUnit 4.
Here's how your imports should look like.

```
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
```

#### Implement a `InstantTaskExecutorExtension`

This is better if you care about using JUnit 5 :)

[Here's an article](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2019/01/17/livedatajunit5/) that talks about how to implement precisely `InstantTaskExecutorExtension`.
Once that's done remember to apply it to your test class using the `@ExtendWith(InstantTaskExecutorExtension::class)` annotation instead of `@Rule`!